# Developer License Error Windows RT (Error 0x90070005)

Tags: c#, windows-rt

I am trying to install an application(my own developed) on windows RT(Qualcomm tablet). during the installation(acquiring the developer license) it gave me an error i.e. "We couldn't get your developer license for Windows RT.(Error 0x90070005).
My windows is Windows RT for testing purpose only. Build 9200.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'd love to know what you did, if you did. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread on the MSDN forums ( http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral/thread/4f6eaf3e-08f4-44e5-816d-43ad172235f5/ ) the problem might be caused by having a password that is too long. Consider changing your password to a shorter one and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my password is only 8 characters long.